# iOS7 Facebook SDK exception on any first call

Tags: ios, facebook

Trying to integrate facebook sdk 3.10 in my existing app. Any first call to a FB function crashes the app. I must be missing something basic here (build setting/initialization code?), but can't figure out what.

The "HelloFacebookSample" app is running fine in the very same environment. Only when from my own app I call, e.g.:

> [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

or

> [FBAppEvents activateApp];

that crashes my app. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add any relevant log messages and code

Comment: actually, your remark pointed me in the right direction. Forgot to set the AppId correctly. solved